# fillna in Pandas - how to choose the best method automatically?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fillna

Suppose I have a dataframe that contains columns with lots and lots of nan values - in fact most values are none, except one (or a few that are identical), but are distributed along different lines. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan, 2, np.nan], 'B':[3.5, np.nan, 3.5], 'C':[np.nan, np.nan, 0.1]})
```

So how can I achieve a dataframe that looks like this?

```
  A    B    C
0  2  3.5  0.1
1  2  3.5  0.1
2  2  3.5  0.1
```

'bfill' would only work for column 'C', 'ffill' only for column 'B'...

So how can I replace all the nan values in the column with the notna value present anywhere and in any number of instances in that column?

Comment: What happens if you have more that non NaN value?

Comment: I don't, but pandas just tends to use the last not NaN value for ffill and the first not Nan value for bfill, so this would just copy the neighbouring values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forwardfill, backfill the dataframe.

```
df =df.ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: Haha, I just did that, pnly in two separate lines and felt rather silly, for sure there must be a more ellegant way of doing it. Didn't realise I can at least do it in one line :) Thanks

Comment: I couldn't a few minutes ago...